# Could not authenticate you twitter

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am getting  an error `could not authenticate you 32`

I am using the correct access tokens and consumer  keys but still getting  this error. 
Anyone can tell what is going on?

**UPDATE 1**

**PHP**
I am using Abraham TwitterOAuth Library

```
require_once("Abraham/TwitterOAuth/autoload.php");
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);

$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

echo json_encode($tweets);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146767/twitter-could-not-authenticate-you-error

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: I am using local host as my urls

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28883601/twitteroauth-from-abraham-could-not-authenticate-you-error-32/29471160#29471160